# Need help on javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

the code below does not work .Could u help me figure out my mistake:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<script>
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    soops();
}

function soops() {
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                alert(i);
                      }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @gengkev why do u have what?

Comment: your code says `<script>``

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong other than that characte @gengkev mentioned, it runs fine here http://jsfiddle.net/X8cjs/

Comment: @gengkev what a silly mistake anyway thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that you are using the same variable `i` in both loops, but in your `soops` function you do not use `var` keyword, i.e. it thinks that `i` is taken from outside. Use this (assuming you want 10 loops to be fired 10 times):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    soops();
}

function soops() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be enough

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    soops();
}

function soops() {
   alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the soops function to this:

```
function soops() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Missing the `var` means that the `i` variable is global which would clash with the `i` variable declared outside the function.

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/vYK2j/

Answer (score 0):

First, change

```
<script>`
```

to

```
<script>
```

Then change the soops function:

```
function soops() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```